# How to switch viewcontrollers programmatically by swipe guesture?

Tags: ios

I want to put the push Navigation into swipe.

i want to call this method on swipe gesture.

```
- (IBAction)MakeADifferenceButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    MakeADifferenceViewController *makeADifferenceView = [[MakeADifferenceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeADifferenceViewController"  bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:makeADifferenceView animated:YES];
    [makeADifferenceView release];
}
```

any-one please help me. i am new in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to add UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft in your current UIView

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MakeADifferenceButtonPressed:)];
swipeleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```